# SQL - Get child nodes and use "for loop" with XML datatype

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have one xml like,

```
Declare @xmldata xml;
set @xmldata ='
<Customers>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Name>foo</Name>      
  <UserName>TestUser</UserName>
  <Password>pwd</Password>
  <Contacts>
    <FirstName>david</FirstName>
    <LastName>lawr</LastName>        
  </Contacts>
  <Contacts>
     <FirstName>john</FirstName>
     <LastName>peter</LastName>         
  </Contacts>  
</Customers>';
```

I want to insert this above xml doc to 2 sql tables. In First Table(Table1) have the fields like Id, Name, UserName, Password fields. and the Second Table(Table2) have the fields like CustomerId, FirstName, LastName.

This xml doc have more than one child nodes like **Contacts**. How to get the Node values and child node values from this xml, and want to insert this data to Table1 and Table2.

Note : If the **Contact** child node comes 2 time means, we will insert the 2 rows in Table2..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.FirstTable(CustomerID, CustomerName, UserName, Password)
    SELECT
        @xmldata.value('(/Customers/Id)[1]', 'int'),
        @xmldata.value('(/Customers/Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        @xmldata.value('(/Customers/UserName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        @xmldata.value('(/Customers/Password)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

Output from the `SELECT` statement is something like:

```
CustomerID  CustomerName   UserName  Password
     1        foo          TestUser  pwd
```

Second query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SecondTable(CustomerID, FirstName, LastName)
    SELECT
        @xmldata.value('(/Customers/Id)[1]', 'int'),
        Cont.value('(FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
        Cont.value('(LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
    FROM
        @xmldata.nodes('/Customers/Contacts') AS Cust(Cont)
```

Output from this `SELECT` is:

```
CustomerID   FirstName  LastName
    1        david      lawr
    1        john       peter
```

Comment: Hi @Marc_s.... Yes, Its working fine... This query only i need     @@@@  Thank you verymuch..!!!!!